# Problems running a javafx application, Netbeans 11, java 12, javafx 13

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

Trying to run a simple hello world example but getting the following error, which I do not understand:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

How to solve it? Do I need some libs, plugins, configs which are not yet included?

Here is my pom:
Tried using Java 9,10,11,12 and JavaFX 12 & 13 and get the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject3.MainApp</mainClass>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo/Medusa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
        <artifactId>Medusa</artifactId>
        <version>11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
        <artifactId>colors</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: have seen that error when the (native?) rendering libs in graphics were not available - for me that could happen when locally compiling jfx and trying to use it from a different project in eclipse: then I needed to point the java.library.path to the directory of those dlls. Don't know anything about how/why/if maven doesn't find them in your context, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug in the dependency `eu.hansolo:Medusa:11.2`, as it depends on `mac` version of JavaFX and hence the modulepath will contain both `win` and `mac` versions of `JavaFX`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>12.0.1</version>
  <classifier>mac</classifier> <---------------
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
  <version>12.0.1</version>
  <classifier>mac</classifier>  <---------------
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
  <version>12.0.1</version>
  <classifier>mac</classifier>  <---------------
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

That was fixed in version `11.3`:

- [Updated some libraries and removed the org.openjfx classifier](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/commit/02d560d8c412da82efa1c5625390a0d7ca1f5b8a)

---

### The solution:

Just update `eu.hansolo:Medusa:11.2` to `eu.hansolo:Medusa:11.3` and it should work.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have found out alone that the problem is the dependency. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @wannaBeDev I am glad that I could help. The bounty would be much helpful reaching 100K ;)

Comment: I didn't know I had to confirm it which I just did. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that you'll break 100k soon.